# How can i loop through string of phone number and remove the leading zero and replace with country code?

Tags: php

How can i loop through string of phone number and remove the leading zero and replace with country code?

**Example:**

I want to replace each leading zero (0) of the phone numbers with "233";

```
$pn_box='08064342060,08052031697,08064342060';
```

Though I tried doing it this way but it converts only the first phone number

```
echo $newNumber = preg_replace('/^0?/', '+'.'233', $pn_num);
```

**Output:**

```
$pn_box='+2338064342060,2338052031697,2338064456763';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use str_replace() function http://php.net/str_replace

Comment: I used preg_replace() function, but it converts only the first phone number

Comment: It gives me funny result; +2338+23364342+2336+233,+2338+23352+23331697,+2338+23364342+2336+233

Comment: It replaced all the zero in the numbers

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$pn_box='08064342060,08052031697,08064342060';

$new_pn_box = array();

$tempArray = explode(',',$pn_box);

foreach($tempArray as $phone_number) {
    $new_pn_box[]='233'.substr($phone_number, 1);
}

$new_pn_box = implode(',',$new_pn_box);

echo $new_pn_box;
```

This will only replace the first 0 of each phone number with '233'.

Comment: no problem, btw if you need to check whether the first digit is a zero '0' then just do a simple if statement inside the foreach loop

Comment: Dear lozza, Is there any way i could check if a number already has 233 in front before assigning 233 to it to avoid replication.